# when i shutdown my pc everything shuts off fine but if i touch my keyboard it turns on again

Tags: windows, corsair

the same thing happens with my mouse but the issue is that I would stay on until I turn my pc on again and shut it down and hope that no one goes to touch it and I've tried lookin thought the icue settings but I cant find anything and just searching it up isn't helping either

Comment: When you tap your keybpard, does it boot up i.e. into the BIOS/UEFI, and then show the windows starting up screen for windows starting up and you wait till windows has loaded?  Or does windows just appear on the screen?  If the former, that's strange. If the latter, then it didn't shut down!

Comment: nothing happens when i touch my keyboard it just lights up but when i press the power button on my pc the tuf gaming logo shows then windows is on the screen

Comment: and what if you try opening a cmd prompt   and run  `shutdown /s /f /t 10` like  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TzOpRyRzOHs

Comment: your title current says that after your computer shuts down then  you touch the keyboard that it "turns on again"

Comment: sorry i meant that the lights in the keyboard turns on again the pc itself does not turn on

Comment: So your computer is going into sleep mode or hibernation mode (I don't recall the difference but they're similar.. I think maybe keyboard might wake sleep mode ebut not hibernation as hibernation is deeper than sleep). This may help https://www.howtogeek.com/262325/why-is-windows-hibernating-instead-of-fully-shutting-down/ something there about windows 8 and windows 10

Comment: it worked!!!!!!! thank you so much i appreciate all your help and patience

Comment: Please state what exactly you discovered and what worked.. You can post your own answer

Answer (score 0):

There are various levels of "shut down" in Windows (and in other OS's, such as Linux).

- **Full shutdown**, without Fast Boot, simply stops all processes and turns off the PC. Other than clock battery, it should use no power. Restarting requires pressing the *power button*.
- **Hibernation** saves an image of memory to disk, and then performs a full shutdown (though some laptops keep using a trickle of power to check if the lid is opened, and then restart). The computer will boot in a few seconds from Hibernation.
- **Sleep or Suspend** keeps the computer running at a slow speed, using a trickle of power. The PC appears to be off, but is ready to restart in a second or two when the lid is opened, when a key is pressed or when the mouse is moved. Evidently, *your* system is in Sleep, not full shutdown.

To completely shut down, adjust the [Power Options](https://geekflare.com/windows-power-options/) so that when the lid is closed or the power button is pressed, the PC either performs a full shutdown or it hibernates. In either of those states, a laptop will not drain the battery, and it will not wake up on key press or mouse action.

However, until you navigate the complexities of the Power Options, you can perform a full shutdown as follows:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>&<kbd>R</kbd>.
- Type `shutdown /s /t 0` to allow programs to terminate gracefully and then shut down, or
- Type `shutdown /s /f /t 0` to abruptly end all programs and shut down.